# Android getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError when resizing an image

Tags: performance, android-imageview, android-image, android-memory

I have an that works fine on my phone. However, when I checked the live crash data, people are getting the Out Of Memory Error.

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

I'm trying to load image from the Photo and trying to make the image smaller.

Here's my code

The requiredSize is 1000

```
 public static Bitmap getImage(Context c, Uri uri, final int requiredSize)
        throws FileNotFoundException {
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(c.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri), null, o);

    int width_tmp = o.outWidth
            , height_tmp = o.outHeight;
    int scale = 1;

    while(true) {
        if(width_tmp / 2 < requiredSize || height_tmp / 2 < requiredSize)
            break;
        width_tmp /= 2;
        height_tmp /= 2;
        scale *= 2;
    }

    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = scale;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(c.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri), null, o2); //This is the line that's getting the error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loading high res images directly in imageview may render your UI laggy. To avoid this, to perform any kind of resizing I will recommend using Picasso or Glide image loading library for better performance with image loading.